# SFML OpenGL Application artifacts - something "wierd" is happening

Tags: graphics, sfml, artifact

Firstly, sorry for the poor question title, I didn't know exactly what to put!

So I have an OpenGL application running from a SFML Window context.

I previously posted a question about poor performance, but that issue seems to be solved now.

As you can see on the images I have uploaded, something rather odd is happening. I don't know really how to describe it, but it looks like the right half of the window shouldn't be there!

[image: Right Hand side of window starts with grey block]

[image: This is an example of what happens after resize]

[image: It looks like 2 OpenGL contexts exist side by side?]

Anyone any ideas on the problem?

Here is my code:

```
sf::ContextSettings settings;
settings.depthBits = 32;
settings.stencilBits = 8;
settings.antialiasingLevel=4;
settings.majorVersion = 3;
settings.minorVersion = 0;

sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "insert title", sf::Style::Default, settings);
window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);


bool running = true;
while(running)
{
    sf::Event e;
    while(window.pollEvent(e))
    {
        if(e.type == sf::Event::Closed)
        {
            running = false;
        }

        if(e.type == sf::Event::Resized)
        {
            glViewport(0, 0, e.size.width, e.size.height);
            gluLookAt(0,0,-1, 0,0,0, 0,1,0);;
        }
    }


    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

    glutSolidSphere(1, 12, 12);

    window.display();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is caused by copying and pasting code.

Above the code shown, I had the lines:

```
sf::ContextSettings settings;
settings.depthBits = 24;
settings.stencilBits = 0;
settings.antialiasingLevel = 0;
settings.majorversion = 3;
settings.minorversion = 2;
```

The minor version was incorrect. Removing the lines ' settings.majorversion = 3;' and 'settings.minorversion = 2;' fixed the issue!

As an experiment I changed the major to 4. This caused the program to crash all together.